# Using a base.html file but modifying more than just the body

Tags: html, django, django-templates

First of all, I have no problems with my code. This question is more of a "Is this possible and if so/not what is the right way of doing it ?"

I have a website where every page has the same look, the differences between them are as follows:

- The homepage has an interactive leaflet map (javascript)
- The titles vary on every page
- The elements in the head tags change from one page to another but not always
- The background image doesn't change
- Within the body tag, I have a div tag containing a page footer common to all pages

What I would like to know is if it is possible to use a base.html template for these pages knowing the above constraints and also, if it is, how I would go about modifying the said pages to do so.

As I said, the code isn't really an issue here but for clarity and for you to be able to see what changes from one page to another, here is the Github repository for the project. (The project is a university project and therefore some parts of the code is in French since my university is a french University)

https://github.com/MaxMichel2/PWEB

Don't hesitate to tell me if some clarifications are needed to understand my issue.

**EDIT**

All the Django tutorials I have seen and read online only explain/talk about the `{% block content %}` delimiters in the `<body>` tags but I haven't found any help on how the have different parts within the `<head>` section.

Is it simply the case of using a different `{% block content %}` delimiter to identify the parts of the base.html file that will have parts added/modified ?

If so would if be possible to have a basic example to see what I'm working towards ?

Comment: Yes, its possible. Your question is too broad.

Comment: I'll add an edit to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `{% include template %}` which is somewhat the opposite of the base-extends, instead of having a base template and extending that, include allows you to add small re-usable parts of codes into your template as in

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <some unique html to the current page>
    {% include 'some_common_html' %}      <---- right here this part doesnt have to be in base.html
    this means that you can include this part anywhere in your templates, without having it inside the base 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This may well be the answer that is the most adapted to my issue even though it's not what I initially thought I would do. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Keep those thing in `base.html` which is common for every page.
Then suppose a specific styles sheet or JavaScript or page title required for specific page not every page then you follow something like this

**base.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <--! common style sheets -->
    {% block page_specific_style %}
    {% endblock %}

    <title>
        {% block title %}
        {% endblock %}
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block page_specific_js %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Lets say you need to add a new style sheet to `contact.html`, not any other page

**contact.html**

```
{% load static %}
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block page_specific_style %}
    <link href="{% static 'some.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}
    This is contact page title
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    content of contact page
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I wish I could accept 2 answers because This answer also does what I would like perfectly well but may not be the most fitting to my issue. Nonetheless I thank you for the time spent answering and will most likely use this on certain files where it is more adapted than the other answer. Thank you

Comment: You can do some study for better understanding https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/performance/#template-performance